# Adding newline to clipboard with pyperclip?

Tags: python, clipboard

I'm using pyperclip (the python module that allows you to put stuff in the clipboard) and while it's good for putting single lines, what if I want to make the user copy many lines? Putting '/n' only copies '/n' directly into the string. What else can I do? This is the windows function from pyperclip:

```
def winSetClipboard(self, text):
    text = str(text)
    GMEM_DDESHARE = 0x2000
    ctypes.windll.user32.OpenClipboard(0)
    ctypes.windll.user32.EmptyClipboard()
    try:
        # works on Python 2 (bytes() only takes one argument)
        hCd = ctypes.windll.kernel32.GlobalAlloc(GMEM_DDESHARE, len(bytes(text))+1)  # @UndefinedVariable
    except TypeError:
        # works on Python 3 (bytes() requires an encoding)
        hCd = ctypes.windll.kernel32.GlobalAlloc(GMEM_DDESHARE, len(bytes(text, 'ascii'))+1)  # @UndefinedVariable
    pchData = ctypes.windll.kernel32.GlobalLock(hCd)  # @UndefinedVariable
    try:
        # works on Python 2 (bytes() only takes one argument)
        ctypes.cdll.msvcrt.strcpy(ctypes.c_char_p(pchData), bytes(text))
    except TypeError:
        # works on Python 3 (bytes() requires an encoding)
        ctypes.cdll.msvcrt.strcpy(ctypes.c_char_p(pchData), bytes(text, 'ascii'))
    ctypes.windll.kernel32.GlobalUnlock(hCd)  # @UndefinedVariable
    ctypes.windll.user32.SetClipboardData(1, hCd)
    ctypes.windll.user32.CloseClipboard()
```

Comment: _"Putting '/n' only copies '/n' directly into the string."_. `/n` is not the escape sequence for a newline. What happens when you try `\n`?

Comment: `pyperclip` doesn't currently support Unicode on Windows. I've submitted [a patch](https://github.com/asweigart/pyperclip/pull/8/files) to fix that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, `'\n'` is the correct escape for a newline. Additionally, Windows line endings are `'\r\n'`.